# Still pausing/resuming and start a new game is not working good. Can'r figure what should I do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First a screenshot of my Hierarchy :

Everything is inside a one scene name The :

The game start when Main Game is disabled. Inside Main Game sit all the game objects. The Main Menu and Game Manager are enabled.

When running the game first time, When the game start there is short animation of the player for 5 seconds. The player start from some rotating degrees on Z. Z = 50 when x and y both are 0. Then the player is rotating slowly over the Z to 0.

It's like the player is sleeping and awake up.
I'm using post processing stack by unity.

And here is the first problem. While the player is rotating on the Z and post processing effect is working if I press the Escape key it will bring me back to the Main Menu but then if I press the Escape key again it will start the game over again from the begin.

But if I'm waiting in my game for the player to finish rotating on the Z and the post processing effect is finished and then pressing on Escape it will bring the main menu and second time will resume the game from the same point.

I can't figure out why when the player is rotating and the post process is working the escape key make it start the game over again from the being ?

[image: Hierarchy]

This is a screenshot of the game when start and after finish the rotating and the process stack :

[image: On the left when the game start cutscene on the right starting a conversation]

Another problem I noticed now. After the game start using the post process and the player rotating finished if I press Escape it will go to main menu and escape again will be back to the game but for example in the second screenshot the conversation is not continue. It will return to the same point in the game but things not seems to continue like the conversation.

On the Back to main menu object I have a script attached to it :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool _isInMainMenu = false;
    public GameObject mainGame;
    public GameObject mainMenu;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (!_isInMainMenu)
            {
                // -- Code to freeze the game
                mainGame.SetActive(false);
                mainMenu.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                // -- Code to unfreeze the game
                mainGame.SetActive(true);
                mainMenu.SetActive(false);
            }

            _isInMainMenu = !_isInMainMenu;
        }
    }
}
```

On the Main Menu object under Main Menu I have attached this script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mainGame;
    public GameObject mainMenu;

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        mainGame.SetActive(true);
        mainMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

On the PLAY button I'm using this script method PlayGame from the MainMenu script.

In the Main Game object on the Player object attached to thew Player I have some scripts the controller :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float translatioin = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        float straffe = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        translatioin *= Time.deltaTime;
        straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(straffe, 0, translatioin);
    }
}
```

Player Lock Manager :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerCameraMouseLook playerCameraMouseLook;
    public PlayerController playerController;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void PlayerLockState(bool LockPlayer, bool LockPlayerCamera)
    {
        if (LockPlayer == true)
        {
            playerController.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            playerController.enabled = true;
        }

        if (LockPlayerCamera == true)
        {
            playerCameraMouseLook.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            playerCameraMouseLook.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And Mouse Lock State :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLockState : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool lockState = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        LockState(lockState);
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }

    public void LockState(bool lockState)
    {
        if (lockState == false)
        {
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.visible = false;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
    }
}
```

Under the Player as child I have the Player Camera object and attached to the Player Camera also some scripts :

Player Camera Mouse Look :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCameraMouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;

    private GameObject player;
    private Vector2 mouseLook;
    private Vector2 smoothV;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        player = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
        mouseLook += smoothV;

        mouseLook.y = Mathf.Clamp(mouseLook.y, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
        player.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

And Depth Of Field script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.PostProcessing;

public class DepthOfField : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public PostProcessingProfile postProcessingProfile;
    public bool dephOfFieldFinished = false;
    public PlayerLockManager playerLockManager;

    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private float clipLength;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerAnimator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();

        AnimationClip[] clips = playerAnimator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;
        foreach (AnimationClip clip in clips)
        {
            clipLength = clip.length;
        }

        var depthOfField = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;
        depthOfField.focalLength = 300;
        StartCoroutine(changeValueOverTime(depthOfField.focalLength, 1, clipLength));
        postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = depthOfField;
    }

    IEnumerator changeValueOverTime(float fromVal, float toVal, float duration)
    {
        playerLockManager.PlayerLockState(true, true);

        float counter = 0f;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            var dof = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;

            if (Time.timeScale == 0)
                counter += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
            else
                counter += Time.deltaTime;

            float val = Mathf.Lerp(fromVal, toVal, counter / duration);

            dof.focalLength = val;
            postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = dof;

            yield return null;
        }

        playerAnimator.enabled = false;
        dephOfFieldFinished = true;
    }
}
```

I have under Main Game also a object name Openning Scene and attached to it :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpeningCutscene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NaviConversations naviConversation;
    public DepthOfField dephOfField;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (dephOfField.dephOfFieldFinished == true)
        {
            naviConversation.PlayNaviConversation(0);
            dephOfField.dephOfFieldFinished = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit long but everything is connected.

1. The game start with the main menu.
2. When clicking the PLAY button a new game start.
3. When a new game start the script Depth Of Field is in action using the post processing. Also I'm locking the player so the player will not be able to move either the mouse or the player it self.
4. When the depth of field script finished his work a conversation between Navi and the Player start. When a conversation is in action the player can move the mouse 360 degrees but cant move the player to any direction.
5. When the conversation ended the player can also move to any direction.

Problems :

1. When start a new game while the depth of field script is in work pressing escape will bring the main menu but pressing escape again will not resume the depth of field script but will start it all over again.
2. When waiting the conversation to end if not pressing escape until the conversation ended then when moving around and pressing escape it will bring the main menu and again will resume the game from the same point.
3. The problems is when the game is doing something like the depth of field it will start the game over again instead resuming or when in conversation in the middle the conversation will never continue.
4. The ides with the escape key is once to get to main menu and second to resume the game.
5. The PLAY button is what should only start a new game and not the escape key.

It's a bit long but everything is connected.

Comment: When you disable the "main game" and enable it again, all the game objects and mono scripts will have Start() called again. Check to see if that is creating your problems

Comment: I would also suggest moving all activation, deactivation and mouse lock code into a single function, and calling that from the GameManager

Answer (score 0):

I can't see which objects you hooked up to `mainGame` and `mainMenu` in `BackToMainMenu` from your hierarchy, so I have some conjecture in here.
Sounds like you want Escape key to pause, and unpause, as well as bring up a menu, you want Play button in the menu to restart your game.
However, in both `MainMenu` and `BackToMainMenu` you use the same code:

```cs
    mainGame.SetActive(true);
    mainMenu.SetActive(false);
```

This just turns the objects on and off in the hierarchy. This means the *first time* you do one of these things, all objects turned on under the gameobject referenced by `mainGame` will run their `Awake` and `Start` methods, but not the second time. Also depending which objects are active (like I said I can't fully see what component is on what object and which objects are referenced by which serialized field) you might be able to introduce a state error on `BackToMainMenu._isInMainMenu` because that field isn't changed when you hit play. Here is a fantastic image showing execution timeline in Unity: 
[Monobehavior Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8DPJ.png)

In summary:

1. The second time you run the game `DepthOfField` won't call `Start` a second time. Instead try `OnEnable`.
2. The conversation and game logic is not shown in your post, but likely it also is initializing in `Start` and won't run a second time.
3. A bit of trickiness around Coroutines is likely to blame here. When `DepthOfField` starts it also starts a coroutine. That coroutine *keeps going even if you set the gameobject inactive*. So you run the game once, that coroutine starts, you turn the object off when you hit escape, the coroutine finishes, you hit play again, but `DepthOfField.dephOfFieldFinished == true` and your playerAnimator is disabled and won't enable again.
4. Also 5. This kind of behavior can be tricky and is usually dependent on what else you have going on in your scene. Since you have one scene with everything at once, you need to watch out for putting stuff in `Awake` and `Start` since this will only run once. Instead you can try a number of things, my favorite is usually to set up a singleton or static class that works as a state machine for the whole scene. It will call custom `Initialize` functions in your behaviors instead of using `Awake` and `Start`.

Keep references to your coroutines by doing things like:

```cs
    private Coroutine depthOfFieldRoutineRef;

    private OnEnable()
    {
        if (depthOfFieldRoutineRef != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(depthOfFieldRoutineRef);
        }

        depthOfFieldRoutineRef = 
            StartCoroutine(changeValueOverTime
            (depthOfField.focalLength, 1, clipLength));
        // Don't forget to set depthOfFieldRoutineRef to null again at the end of routine!
    }
```

For simple pausing behavior you can also try setting `Time.timescale = 0;` and back to 1 when you want play to resume.

Less a question than a set of problems, hopefully this set of solutions helps!

Tutorial on [Awake and Start](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/awake-and-start)

Docs on [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Docs on [Time.timescale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)